# Oracle data insertion raising 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in position 87: ordinal not in range(128) error

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert `Portuguese` text into my table. But, it is giving `'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea'` error.

Here is what I am doing :

```
   os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"

   query = "INSERT INTO MESSAGE (MESSAGE,LANGUAGE) VALUES (:MESSAGE,:LANGUAGE)"
   data = {'MESSAGE': '..... assistência para ajuda responda AJUDA Sua', 'LANGUAGE': 'Portuguese'}
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute(query, data)
   .....
```

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGE  (   
    language  VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL, 
    message  NVARCHAR2(350) NOT NULL
);
```

I am not sure if I need to set anything to insert other characters into the database.

Comment: tried using NLS_LANG = 'UTF8' ?

Comment: Yes. I did. But, no luck yet.

Comment: Your Query part is ok. seems like python Encoding issue. check out this similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` (with the dot) is the correct syntax.

Comment: Which editor do you use to write your python script? Check character settings in your editor - is it set to UTF-8?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I am using sublime and have set `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit , following the comment : https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/5#issuecomment-288268711,  I set the value of `NLS_LANG`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to set the environment variable NLS_LANG you **must** do it before you create any connection; otherwise, it will have no effect. Better yet, however, is to use the following to create the connection as this does not depend on environment variables:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/password@connectString",
        encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: this saving my life!